# Why the class of isomorphism classes of sets is large (from the book Basic Category Theory)

Tags: category-theory, set-theory

In [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9WL4.png) paragraph, it says that "Proposition 3.2.4 states that the class of isomorphism classes of sets is large". And [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HS0b.png) is the Proposition 3.2.4.

I don't understand how to use Prop 3.2.4 to prove the statement. My best guess is to pose $I=\text{all the set}$, and $A_i = \text{isomorphism class of }i$. But this wouldn't work because $I$ is not a set and we don't know a priori if $A_i$ is a set or not.

May anyone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leinster is claiming that the class of isomorphism classes is not a set. That is a class of classes; whether or not each $A_i$ is a set is irrelevant, as far as my limited knowledge of set theory can tell (I think that whether or not a class $A_i$ can be set-small may depend on the model you’re working in - I would appreciate it if a reader could clarify that point for me).

Were this class of isomorphism classes a set, that means there is some set $I$, sets $B_i$ for each $i\in I$, for which any set $X$ has $X\cong B_i$ for some $i$. But this stands in direct contradiction to Proposition $3.2.4$, as $I$ is set-small.

Comment: > whether or not each $A_i$ is a set is irrelevant $$$$
This is wrong, It is important that each $A_i$ is a set, in NBG (or even in MK), a "class" is a collection of **sets**. A collection of classes is sometimes called "conglomerate" (conglomerate does not exists in NBG/MK similarly to how classes don't formally exist in ZFC)

Comment: @ℋolo My limited knowledge comes back to haunt me. Thank you. So does that mean, "the class of isomorphism classes" doesn't even make sense to talk about in NBG (say) unless the isomorphism classes are all set-small? Related: on one hand, my intuition tells me the isomorphism class for a set is always too large to be a set, but perhaps in some models this isn't true. Do you know?

Comment: "the class of isomorphism classes",  you forgot the important "**of sets**". This question is a bit tricky, it is in fact makes sense to talk about it using something called [Scott's trick](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott%27s_trick),  which allow us to reduce "collection of disjoint classes" into a "collection of disjoint sets", which is a "class of disjoint sets"

Comment: "intuition tells me the isomorphism class for a set is always too large to be a set, but perhaps in some models this isn't true", an isomorphism class of a specific (non-empty) set is indeed never a set, but using Scott's trick that I mentioned above, we can still talk about it as if it is a set. In fact, before the Axiom of Choice became standard, isomorphism classes + Scott's trick were the standard way to define cardinality in ZF